# Magento 2 - I just want a file upload code

Tags: magento2, image-upload, file-upload

I already sent the file from phtml to controller and in the controller, I need to save that file into a directory
here are HTML and PHP code.

```
<form class="myformdynamic" onsubmit="return Validate()" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('helloworld/index/result');?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="profileAdd" name="profileAdd"><span class="s"id="sfile"></span>
    <button type="submit" id="btnsave" class="action submit primary">
        <span >Save</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

> Here is my code `Result.php` controller in another file,

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Result extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $fileName=['profileAdd']['name'];
        echo $fileName;
        //name of the file is printed which i uploaded from form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload using at `\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory`.

```
protected $_mediaDirectory;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
 
public function __construct(
    Context $context,        
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
) {
    $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try{
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');        
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'profileAdd']); //Since in this example the input controller name is 'profileAdd', it shoud be used here
        /** Allowed extension types */
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);
        /** rename file name if already exists */
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
        $result = $uploader->save($target);
        if ($result['file']) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );            
}
```

Comment: sir it is still showing some error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index\Result::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Filesystem, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var\generation\Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index\Result\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in

Comment: delete all file from var/genearete and recompile

Comment: sir after this line some errors  are showing  $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');    what should i write in in place of               fileId=>'file'

Comment: thanku sir problem is solved

Comment: would you please also tell me how should fetch image fromthat uploaded folder

Comment: can can get $result variable. Just var_dump($result) and see what happen

Comment: @AmitBera Can you please tell me answer to this question. I followed your code for this. -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287256/the-image-file-was-not-uploaded-error-in-magento-2-while-editing-the-grid-form

Comment: I am little bit busy now and will reply later

Comment: @AmitBera I am hoping that you will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: @AmitBera, great, its working. How can I upload the form as a Ajax. Please guide