# The image file was not uploaded error in Magento 2 while editing the grid form

Tags: magento2, adminform, image-upload, file-upload

I am getting the file was not uploaded error in Magento 2 when I edit the form in the Magento 2 backend. 
[image]

When I try to save the form it shows an error. The problem is that it requires me to choose the image again even though it is already there. Kindly help me to resolve this problem. 
[image]

My save.php file.

```
<?php

namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \AdminGrid\Grid\Model\GridFactory
     */
    var $gridFactory;
    protected $_mediaDirectory;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \AdminGrid\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->gridFactory = $gridFactory;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;

    }

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();


        try{

            $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');

            $targetOne = "mycustomfolder/";
            /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
            /** Allowed extension types */
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);
            /** rename file name if already exists */
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
            $result = $uploader->save($target);

        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }


        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $data['image'] = $targetOne.$result['file'];

        if (!$data) {
            $this->_redirect('grid/grid/addrow');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
            $rowData->setData($data);
            if (isset($data['id'])) {
                $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
            }
            $rowData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');


    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Webkul_Grid::save');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Webkul\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \AdminGrid\Grid\Model\GridFactory
     */
    var $gridFactory;
    protected $_mediaDirectory;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $adapterFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \AdminGrid\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Webkul\Grid\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $file
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->gridFactory = $gridFactory;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->_file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) {
        try {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Webkul\Grid\Model\Grid');
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
        try{

            $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');

            $targetOne = "mycustomfolder/";
            /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
            /** Allowed extension types */
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);

            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            $uploader->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
            /** rename file name if already exists */
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
            $result = $uploader->save($target);

            if (!$result) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $target)
                );
            }

            $data['image'] = $targetOne.$result['file'];

        }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        }

        if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                    $_mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead($this->directoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
                    $file = $data['image']['value'];
                    $imgPath = $_mediaDirectory.$file;
                    if ($this->_file->isExists($imgPath))  {
                        $this->_file->deleteFile($imgPath);
                    }
                    $data['image'] = NULL;
                }
                if (isset($data['image']['value'])){
                    $data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
                }
                $inputFilter = new \Zend_Filter_Input(
                    [],
                    [],
                    $data
                );
                $data = $inputFilter->getUnescaped();
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if ($id) {
                    $model->load($id);
                    if ($id != $model->getId()) {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The wrong item is specified.'));
                    }
                }
                $model->setData($data);
                $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session');
                $session->setPageData($model->getData());
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the item.'));
                $session->setPageData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('grid/*/editrow', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('grid/*/');
                return;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if (!empty($id)) {
                    $this->_redirect('grid/*/editrow', ['id' => $id]);
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('grid/*/index');
                }
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the item data. Please review the error log.')
                );
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setPageData($data);
                $this->_redirect('grid/*/editrow', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('grid/*/');
    }



    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Webkul_Grid::save');
    }
}
```